# click on element not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to click on chat items on the web telegram page. The thing is it used to work perfectly fine last week, today I wanted to edit some other section of the code when I discovered that the click() function doesn't work anymore.
in my content.js I have :

```
function scrapChannelOnnewMSG(titleChannel,accountslist){
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-list custom-scroll");
  var scrollelem = element[0].children[0];
  // for all chat channels, do
  for (var i = 0; i < scrollelem.children.length; i++) {
   scrollelem.children[i].children[0].click();
          console.log("just clicked");
// do stuff with the resulting elemnts
```

Any idea why this is happening? I stress that it was working just fine before today.

Comment: So probably Telegram changed their code. Maybe they are checking for `isTrusted` on the click event or they use a different event now.

Comment: How can I check for which possibilities is more probable ?

Comment: Debug it in devtools.

Comment: so I can perform the click on other parts of the DOM ( dropdown menu) but I can't click on the chat items. Console logs give a 'isTrue=false' . Is there a way around this ? I found this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/mv2-archive/api/debugger/pause-resume/background.js but I need it on content.js not background.